# How to create a menu bar and a submenu with JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

How do I create a menu bar and a submenu with [JSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces) 2.0?

I use [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) 6.8 and server [GlassFish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish).

There are many JSF components ([RichFaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RichFaces), [PrimeFaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces#Ajax-enabled_components_and_frameworks), etc.) which you advised me to use and gave me steps for implementation. What would be some example code source?

Answer (score 2):

From your question it's not quite clear if you are open to use component libs or not. I assume the first:

With Primefaces there is a a component `<p:menu>` that gives you all you need. Here is an example from the [Primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu.jsf):

```
<p:menu type="tiered" style="width:180px">  
    <p:submenu label="Ajax Menuitems" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-refresh">  
        <p:menuitem value="Save" actionListener="#{buttonBean.save}" update="messages" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-disk" />  
        <p:menuitem value="Update" actionListener="#{buttonBean.update}" update="messages" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w" />  
    </p:submenu>  
    <p:submenu label="Non-Ajax Menuitem" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-newwin">  
        <p:menuitem value="Delete" actionListener="#{buttonBean.delete}" update="messages" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-close"/>  
    </p:submenu>  
    <p:submenu label="Navigations" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-extlink">  
        <p:submenu label="Prime Links">  
            <p:menuitem value="Prime" url="http://www.prime.com.tr" />  
            <p:menuitem value="PrimeFaces" url="http://www.primefaces.org" />  
        </p:submenu>  
        <p:menuitem value="TouchFaces" url="#{request.contextPath}/touch" />  
    </p:submenu>  
</p:menu>
```

This will create a menu with submenus.